# Html elements not showing properly after appending a group of elements using jquery append

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a group of elements in a div that I am trying to append to a parent div when a button is clicked. Upon appending, the view of the div does not show properly. I copied the appended div using my browser's inspect element and placed in my code directly and reloaded the page, the view was displayed as expected. So it appears the issue is during appending. How do I fix this issue?

Here is the code:

```js
function addNewRow(){
            let theList = $('#officeDraggableDiv');
            let line = '<div class="nk-tb-item office-draggable-list" draggable="true"><div class="nk-tb-col nk-tb-col-check"><div class="custom-control custom-control-sm custom-checkbox notext"> <em class="icon ni ni-move doc-list"></em></div></div><div class="nk-tb-col"><div class="user-card"> <input type="text" class="form-control border-transparent form-focus-none" placeholder="Search by user or email"></div></div><div class="nk-tb-col tb-col-mb"> <select class="form-select form-select-sm" data-search="off" data-placeholder="Bulk Action"><option value="">Bulk Action</option> </select></div><div class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md"> <select class="form-select form-select-sm" data-search="off" data-placeholder="Bulk Action"><option value="">Bulk Action</option> </select></div><div class="nk-tb-col tb-col-lg"> <select class="form-select form-select-sm" data-search="off" data-placeholder="Bulk Action"><option value="">Bulk Action</option> </select></div></div>';
            theList.append(line);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I think you use a custom select box if yes then call the custom select box function after appending your HTML

Comment: @LaljiTadhani You are absolutely right. Any hint on how I can call the custom select function please? When I used the default select button, it displayed well

Comment: custom select which library use

Comment: @LaljiTadhani I am using a template. It appears that the custom select has been integrated with the main css file, so I cannot separate it in a sense

Comment: add your HTML & CSS & JS Code here so i can reproduce

Comment: @LaljiTadhani I have found a way around it. The select2 link was in the template documentation, I have called the select two again after appending, it works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of function please do it with event

```
$(document).on('click',"#btn_add_office",function(){
        let theList = $('#officeDraggableDiv');
        let line = '<div class="nk-tb-item office-draggable-list" draggable="true"><div class="nk-tb-col nk-tb-col-check"><div class="custom-control custom-control-sm custom-checkbox notext"> <em class="icon ni ni-move doc-list"></em></div></div><div class="nk-tb-col"><div class="user-card"> <input type="text" class="form-control border-transparent form-focus-none" placeholder="Search by user or email"></div></div><div class="nk-tb-col tb-col-mb"> <select class="form-select form-select-sm" data-search="off" data-placeholder="Bulk Action"><option value="">Bulk Action</option> </select></div><div class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md"> <select class="form-select form-select-sm" data-search="off" data-placeholder="Bulk Action"><option value="">Bulk Action</option> </select></div><div class="nk-tb-col tb-col-lg"> <select class="form-select form-select-sm" data-search="off" data-placeholder="Bulk Action"><option value="">Bulk Action</option> </select></div></div>';
        theList.append(line);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an error in some other part of the code. The function you showed works find when I tested it.

Here's the link to the code in playcode.io:
[playcode.io](https://playcode.io/640920/)

You could write your code like this:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
  addNewRow();
});

function addNewRow() {
  let theList = $('#officeDraggableDiv');
  let line =
    '<div class="nk-tb-item office-draggable-list" draggable="true"><div class="nk-tb-col nk-tb-col-check"><div class="custom-control custom-control-sm custom-checkbox notext"> <em class="icon ni ni-move doc-list"></em></div></div><div class="nk-tb-col"><div class="user-card"> <input type="text" class="form-control border-transparent form-focus-none" placeholder="Search by user or email"></div></div><div class="nk-tb-col tb-col-mb"> <select class="form-select form-select-sm" data-search="off" data-placeholder="Bulk Action"><option value="">Bulk Action</option> </select></div><div class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md"> <select class="form-select form-select-sm" data-search="off" data-placeholder="Bulk Action"><option value="">Bulk Action</option> </select></div><div class="nk-tb-col tb-col-lg"> <select class="form-select form-select-sm" data-search="off" data-placeholder="Bulk Action"><option value="">Bulk Action</option> </select></div></div>';
  theList.append(line);
}
```